# Encoding Bitmap failed

Tags: java, android, opencv

I am trying to send a livestream from my computer to Android.
To capture the frame I use a C++ programm.

First I will tell you what my idea is:
The C++ programm capture a frame using OpenCV and convert it to a size, which the Android APP sends before. This works fine. To send the frame over the UDP Socket I split the data of the frame in parts of 64000 bytes. If the packet size is below 64000 the frame is transferred completly. I also developed a vala client, which recieved the data a shows the image. Everything works fine:

```
socket_source.set_callback ((socket, condition) => {
                try {
                    uint8 data[64000];

                    var received = socket.receive (data);

                    bits_per_second += (uint64) received * 8;

                    buffer.append_vals (data, data.length);

                    if (received < data.length) {
                        show_frame_from_data (buffer.data);

                        frames_per_second++;

                        buffer = new Array<uint8> ();
                    }
                } catch (Error e) {
                    control_bar.set_status (e.message);
                }

                return true;
            });
```

Now I try to implement this in Java/Android, but this doesn't work pretty well. If the frame is smaller than 64000 bytes (only one packet), everything works fine, but if the frame is greater than 64000bytes (more packets), I get very strange pictures on my Android Phone. This picture is only one frame. The size of the gray area changes rapidly.

[image: android phone]

This is my Java Code:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream byteOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    byte[] imageBytes = new byte[65535];

    DatagramPacket imageDataPacket;

    int receivedBytes = 0;

    do {
       imageDataPacket = new DatagramPacket(imageBytes, imageBytes.length);

        try {
            udpSocket.receive(imageDataPacket);

            byteOutputStream.write(imageDataPacket.getData(), 0 , imageDataPacket.getLength());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Log.i("Size:" , "PACKET:" + imageDataPacket.getLength());

    } while(imageDataPacket.getLength() >= 64000);

    Log.i("Size:", "FULL:" + byteOutputStream.size());

    return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(byteOutputStream.toByteArray()));
}
```

The debug output looks right:

```
09-20 22:06:09.786  28087-28231/? I/Size:﹕ PACKET:64000
09-20 22:06:09.808  28087-28231/? I/Size:﹕ PACKET:64000
09-20 22:06:09.810  28087-28231/? I/Size:﹕ PACKET:4014
09-20 22:06:09.810  28087-28231/? I/Size:﹕ FULL:132014
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You did not tell how many bytes were send in total. And where you see grey?

Comment: Have a look in the debug output. "FULL" is the total count of bytes. This is right. I have compare this with the sender. I have added a picture, which shows the grey area.

Comment: In the post, before "This is the Java Code", I can see it.https://photos-1.dropbox.com/t/2/AAAvZnt7gbrIuTscBDieaOtIzIEnEWausVsQxD0uU1c18A/12/166686854/png/32x32/1/1442786400/0/2/android.png/CIbhvU8gASACIAMgBCAFIAYgBygH/8HuEY137QPtrMFaRgvqh-PEIeyDcQaPzEvDn5dlDo3c?size=1280x960&size_mode=2